# LinkGenerator returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I defined a Blazor page with the following directive:

```
@page "section/{name}/details"
```

and I'm trying to generate a link to it from another page using the `LinkGenerator`:

```
var absoluteUri = this.LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage(this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext, "/section/{name}/details", values: new { name = "mysection" });
```

Anyway, `absoluteUri` is always **null**.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LinkGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is used for generating URLs for the *server-side* endpoint routing. It is able to generate links to endpoints that are known to the endpoint routing mechanism, i.e. things like MVC actions, Razor pages, or named routes.

Blazor *pages* are part of the client-side routing mechanism though (yes, even with server-side Blazor), and as such they don’t take part in the server-side routing mechanism. That’s why I don’t believe that the LinkGenerator could possibly generate URLs for client-side routing.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of an alternative that uses Blazor routing. So I think you will have to generate the URL manually, or build your own tool to generate the link. Since you are using server-side Blazor, you do have access to the `HttpContext`, so you can use that to generate an absolute URL. Something like this would probably work:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor

…

@code {
    string GetUrl(string sectionName)
    {
        var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        return request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + $"section/{sectionName}/details";
    }
}
```